# C# Reference a property through a string returned from the Console.ReadLine

Tags: c#, string, properties

I'm new to C# and slowly learning as I go forward.
In a console application I want to be able to type in the name of the property I want to display. The problem I stumble upon is that ReadLine will return a string and I do not know how to turn that string in to a reference to the actual property.

I wrote a simple example to explain what I'm trying to do.
The example will now only type out whatever input it gets twice.

I have tried `typeof(Person).GetProperty(property).GetValue().ToString()` but all I get is an error message saying that there is no overload for GetValue that takes 0 arguments.

Thanks
Rickard

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;

namespace AskingForHelp1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.FirstName = "Mike";
            p.LastName = "Smith";
            p.Age = 33;

            p.displayInfo(Console.ReadLine());
        }
    }

    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public UInt16 Age { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            FirstName = "";
            LastName = "";
            Age = 0;
        }

        public void displayInfo(string property)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(property + ": " + property);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried without GetValue()? Usually the ToString() Method will handle this for you.

Comment: "I'm new to C#" - and starting with reflection already? It may be completely reasonable, but just in case it's not clear to you (don't know what "new" concretely means for you), this is not the way one is *normally supposed* to access properties, or any members, in C#.

Comment: C# Reflection is what you needed. more about it at: [link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17269/Reflection-in-C-Tutorial).
I will also mention that Reflection isn't for newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will give you what you are looking for.

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            Person p = new Person();
            p.FirstName = "Mike";
            p.LastName = "Smith";
            p.Age = 33;
            Console.WriteLine("List of properties in the Person class");
            foreach (var pInfo in typeof (Person).GetProperties())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("\t"+ pInfo.Name);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Type in name of property for which you want to get the value and press enter.");
            var property = Console.ReadLine();
            p.displayInfo(property);
    }


    class Person
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public UInt16 Age { get; set; }

        public Person()
        {
            FirstName = "";
            LastName = "";
            Age = 0;
        }

        public void displayInfo(string property)
        {
            // Note this will throw an exception if property is null 
            Console.WriteLine(property + ": " + this.GetType().GetProperty(property).GetValue(this, null));
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should use smth like this:

```
public static object GetPropValue( object src, string propName )
 {
    return src.GetType( ).GetProperty( propName ).GetValue( src, null );
 }
```

As second parameter is an index:
index
Type: System.Object[]
Optional index values for indexed properties. This value should be null for non-indexed  properties.

Answer (score 0):

`GetValue` needs an *instance* of your class to actually get value *from*. Like this:

```
typeof(Person).GetProperty(property).GetValue(this).ToString()
// to be used in a non-static method of Person
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to give the GetValue function the reference of the object that contains the property.

you need to change your displayInfo function:

`public void displayInfo(string property, Person p)`

then in this function you can call the GetValue function